# Flash: get absolute position of e.currentTarget

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay, wasn't sure about the title.
But here's what I am trying to achieve:

Basically i am trying to do something like a quiz, where you can drag and drop the answers into a field. And if they are correkt it should snap the answer field position.

It should be something like

```
if(myobject.hitTestObject(targetField) && isCorrectAnswer()) {
   myobject.x = targetField.x;
   myobject.y = targetField.y;
}
```

But it's not really working.

So here is what I have:

```
/**
* Generating dragable answer fields based on an array.
**/

function generateAnswer():void {

// creating text format
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 

myFormat.color = 0x0066FF;    
myFormat.size = 24;  
myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER 

// reference array to store all textfields
var referenceArray:Array = new Array();

// iterate through all answers in vocabListItems and generate textfields
var i:int; 

for (i = 0; i < vocabListItems.length; i++) { 
    var answerField:TextField = new TextField();   
    // Setting text to current answer
    answerField.text = vocabListItems[i];    
    answerField.width = 140;    
    answerField.height = 40;    
    answerField.x = 60+ i*150;    
    answerField.y = 410;  
    answerField.background = true;
    answerField.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
    answerField.setTextFormat(myFormat);  
    answerField.selectable = false;
    answerField.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC

    // store the textfield in a container so drag and drop
    // will work
    var textContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    textContainer.addChild(answerField);
    addChild(textContainer);
    referenceArray.push(textContainer);
}

for each (var item in referenceArray) {
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}
}
```

And then I start my drag

```
var start_x:Number;
var start_y:Number;

function startDragging(e: MouseEvent):void {

  var object = e.currentTarget;
  start_x = e.currentTarget.x;
  start_y = e.currentTarget.y;
  object.startDrag();
}
```

And my stop dragging

```
function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void {
e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(targetField)) {
    e.currentTarget.x = targetField.x;
    e.currentTarget.y = targetField.y;

} else {
    e.currentTarget.x = start_x;
    e.currentTarget.y = start_y;
}
}
```

So the problem however is, that e.currentTarget.x is starting from 0. And not from the absolute position on the screen. Its always a relative value, so if i drag it to the targetField its x and y is something like -100, -40

If I set it to the targetField x and y it disappears somewhere in the nirvana of the screen.

targetField is in this case just a rectangle drawn on the stage with a x and y of 160

How can I position it to the absolute x and y?

Here's a screenshot

[image]

So the top field is the targetField which is only a rectangle with x 161 and y 191.

The field on the bottom are the dragable fields which are the e.currentTarget. But currentTarget.x is always 0.

Comment: A display object has a `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal` function built in,  you can use those methods translate your coordinate to global and then back to local on the object you need to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Your `e.currentTarget` is going to be the `textContainer`, which you haven't set an `x/y` on so it will naturally be 0.

It would seem to make more sense to move the container, and not the actual text field when you create it, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < vocabListItems.length; i++) { 
    var answerField:TextField = new TextField();   
    // Setting text to current answer
    answerField.text = vocabListItems[i];    
    answerField.width = 140;    
    answerField.height = 40;    
    //answerField.x = 60+ i*150;      //don't move the text field, move the container later
    //answerField.y = 410;  
    answerField.background = true;
    answerField.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
    answerField.setTextFormat(myFormat);  
    answerField.selectable = false;
    answerField.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC

    // store the textfield in a container so drag and drop
    // will work
    var textContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    textContainer.x = 60+ i*150;
    textContainer.y = 410;

    textContainer.addChild(answerField);
    addChild(textContainer);
    referenceArray.push(textContainer);

    //Also, as an aside, there is no reason to loop through the array after this, just add the listeners here
    textContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    textContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}
```

**End Edit**

---

To translate the coordinates from one object to another, you can use the `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal` methods of a display object.

Something like this:

```
var globalPoint:Point = targetField.localToGlobal(new Point());
var destinationLocalPoint:Point = e.currentTarget.parent.globalToLocal(globalPoint);

e.currentTarget.x = destinationLocalPoint.x;
e.currentTarget.y = destinationLocalPoint.y;
```

What I'm doing here, is first, getting the global coordinates of the `targetField`.  So it's taking a point (at 0,0) relative to `targetField` and translating that relative to the `stage`.

Then I'm making a new Point object that takes that global coordnate set, and translate that to the parent of `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Thanks!!
I added the textcontainer later to solve the problem, that you can't drag textfields. So yeah, this solved the problem! Now me e.currentTarget got the right position and e.currentTarget = targetField.x works!